# add a Activity with name 'main' to existing one in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've legacy in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
extensions.getByName<LiquibaseExtension>("liquibase").apply {
    activities.register("main") {
******************
******************
******************
}
```

I need to apply some plugin before this which is already has

```
liquibase {
    activities.register("main") {
************
}
```

And

```
Cannot add a Activity with name 'main' as a Activity with that name already exists.
    at ************************
```

exception as a result.
I don't wanna mess in the plugin, how can I manage this? Can I add or merge them somehow on the fly?